# Parsing key:value strings from query (like search engines)

Tags: java, regex, search-engine

I have a search engine for my website. The back-end of search is implemented in Java. I want to add some advanced search features to my search. These keywords work like Google or Bing's keywords. For instance `filetype:pdf` or `site:example.com`. When I get the query as a `String`, I want to parse these variables and then run the query. Regular Expression seems like the obvious choice but I was wondering if there's a better/faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a valid set of keywords in List `validKeywordLst`

You can use this regex

```
(?<keyword>\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(?<value>\\S+)
```

Your code would be

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(inputSearch);
 if (m.find( )) 
 {
     m.group("keyword");m.group("value");
 }
```

Now you can check if the keyword is valid using `validKeywordLst`

Comment: So you suggest that I stick to `Regex`? That's what came to my mind. Is it the "standard" solution? I mean is Google using this or a more complicated parser for their query engine?